# carbon dioxide and its behaviour in acid base balance

Tags: acid-base, chemical-biology

In human body acid base balance, why and how does the dissolved carbon dioxide increases the hydrogen ion concentration with increasing in its partial pressure..? At the same time bicarbonate ion is staying in same concentration while hydrogen ion are increasing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The disolved carbon dioxide increases the acid content of the human body. This happens when a carbon dioxide molecule bumps into a water molecule. Carbon dioxide makes water break into hydrogen and hydroxide ion. Hydroxide merges with the carbon dioxide molecule creating bicarbonate ion. Sometimes the hydrogen ion can become part of increasing acidity. Sometimes the hydrogen ion combines with the bicarbonate molecule and make carbonic acid. Carbonic acid could turn into carbonate ion and two hydrogen ions. This is what makes the human body acid base balance. The amount of bicarbonate is staying the same because the bicarbonate that does get converted into carbonic acid or carbonate ion an equal amount of bicarbonate is created from water and carbon dioxide. This just results in a huge amount of hydrogen ions.

Comment: Where can I get that in literature? @Roghan Arun

Comment: you can get the link here: http://ion.chem.usu.edu/~sbialkow/Classes/3650/Carbonate/Carbonic%20Acid.html

Comment: If you don't mind ....Do u know Stewart approach to acid base balance in human body